# array_contains() on array of structs Column is not Iterable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 columns that has this schema:

```
root
 |-- parent_column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- item_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_3: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_4: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- child_column: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- item_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- item_2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- item_3: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- item_4: boolean (nullable = false)
```

I wanted to check if the `child_column` exists in the `parent_column` by doing `array_contains(F.col('parent_column'), F.col('child_column'))` but I am running into `Column is not Iterable` error.

Sample data:

```
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
|parent_column                                 | child_column                               | data_check   |
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [1, 2, 3, 4, false]                        |    true      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
|[[1, 2, 3, 4, false]]                         | [6, 7, 8, 9, false]                        |   false      |
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Sample runnable code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([(2, 2, 2,)],)],
    'parent_column:array<struct<item_1:bigint,item_2:bigint,item_3:bigint>>'
)

df = df.withColumn(
    'child_column',
    F.expr("transform(parent_column, x -> struct(x.item_1 as item_1, x.item_2 as item_2, x.item_3 as item_3))")
)

# WITH ERRORS
# df = df.withColumn(
#     'contains',
#     F.array_contains(F.col('parent_column'), F.col('child_column'))
# )

df.show(truncate=False)
```

In my mind I am checking if a struct exists in an *array* of structs. So I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you sample data is off.  I fixed it.  See child column definition. Not sure if this is your problem with the original query.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
...     [([(2, 2, 2,)],)],
...     'parent_column:array<struct<item_1:bigint,item_2:bigint,item_3:bigint>>'
... )
>>> 
>>> df = df.withColumn(
...     'child_column',
...     F.expr("transform(parent_column, x -> struct(x.item_1 as item_1, x.item_2 as item_2, x.item_3 as item_3))")
... )
>>> df = df.withColumn(
...     'child_column',
...     F.expr("transform(parent_column, x -> struct(x.item_1 as item_1, x.item_2 as item_2, x.item_3 as item_3))")[0])
>>> df.withColumn( 'contains',expr(" array_contains(parent_column, child_column )" )).show()
+-------------+------------+--------+
|parent_column|child_column|contains|
+-------------+------------+--------+
|  [[2, 2, 2]]|   [2, 2, 2]|    true|
+-------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Right. My sample data is incorrect. The solution worked using `F.expr(array_contains())`. What's the difference with using `F.array_contains()`? It failed because of that.

Comment: I'll confess that from time to time I find that using an expression works when I feel like a function should work.  My guess is that it's a bug with compile time code vs runtime code.  This is an area that has improved in spark 3.x. But I do find working with arrays sometimes you have to use `expr` to get things to work.

Comment: If you found my comment helpful please upvote. If you are comfortable marking it as the answer I'd appreciate you marking it so when you have time.